# Makefile autocompletion on Mac

Tags: macos, autocomplete, makefile

Makefile's targets are available by completion on Linux but, AFAICS, not on Mac OS (10.8.5).

Is it possible to get completion working with this OS?

Comment: You need to see if you can find (install and/or enable) the approprate bash completion on your machine. I don't know if those ship with OS X or are available via brew or anything like that though.

Comment: @EtanReisner I should have mentioned that completion on Mac OS 10.8 for, e.g. `cd`. Hence I guess some bash completion is already available on the computer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This worked for me on Catalina in the standard zsh terminal

1. Edit the file named `.zshrc` in you home directory this can be done with this command in the terminal `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add the following lines

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:make:*' tag-order 'targets'

autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

3. exit and save by pressing `ctrl + x` and then save `Y`

Comment: Throws this in macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4: ```zsh compinit: insecure files, run compaudit for list.Ignore insecure files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?``` whenever you open a new Terminal. It does autocomplete make with a nice list though.

Comment: Okay that's weird i don't get that warning on my machine, but i'm also currently running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3. Did it only show the warning once or every time you open the terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately every time i open a new tab.

Comment: I have the same problem even with https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions

Comment: I just tested this solution on a Mac Big Sur of a friend of mine and, except a temporary warning about `compinit`, it works like a charm. In contrast, the [solution provided by @Rustavore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044470/1682470) seems to not work anymore (hence I changed the accepted answer).

Answer (score 36):

This seems to achieve simple bash completions for me on El Capitan:

```
# .bashrc
function _makefile_targets {
    local curr_arg;
    local targets;

    # Find makefile targets available in the current directory
    targets=''
    if [[ -e "$(pwd)/Makefile" ]]; then
        targets=$( \
            grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:' Makefile \
            | sed 's/://' \
            | tr '\n' ' ' \
        )
    fi

    # Filter targets based on user input to the bash completion
    curr_arg=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${targets[@]}" -- $curr_arg ) );
}
complete -F _makefile_targets make
```

Here's how this works:

- **complete -F [function name] [command name]** -- this bash builtin register a new completion for [command name] which is generated by the bash function [function name]. So in my code above, if you type `make [TAB][TAB]` into your shell, you'll trigger the `_makefile_targets()` function.
- **if [[ -e "$(pwd)/Makefile" ]]; then** -- make sure there's a Makefile in the current directory, otherwise don't try a bash completion.
- **grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:' Makefile** -- filter every line of Makefile using the regex for a target name like "test:". `-o` means only return the part of the line that matches. For example, given a Makefile target like "test: build package", only "test:" will be returned
- **| sed 's/://'** -- taking the grep results, remove the colon from the end of line
- **| tr '\n' ' '** -- smoosh all targets onto one line, separated by one space

Inside a bash completion function, `complete` sets several environment variables for you. `COMP_WORDS` is an array of the list of available bash completion choises based on what the user typed. `COMP_CWORD` is the index of the currently selected word.

Another very magical builtin `compgen` will take a list of space separately strings and filter them using the currently selected word. I'm not at all clear how that works.

So, the bottom line is that the last two lines in the function filter our list of makefile targets (stored inside `$targets`) and shoves them into an array `COMPREPLY`. The bash completion reads and displays `COMPREPLY`  as choices in the shell.

---

Inspired by:

1. https://gist.github.com/tlrobinson/1073865
2. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/bash-completion-complete/ (Esp 9.)

Comment: I guess adding in `.bashrc` a similar line with `makefile` instead of `Makefile` is enough to take in account makefiles with lowercase name (even if capitalized names is better practice).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé yes! There are quite a few potential makes for makefiles depending on your OS.

Comment: What about included commands in Makefile? I mean block with `-include {other makefile}`

Comment: Doesn't work for nested entry points like "make foo/bar/baz"

Answer (score 6):

If you use bash and homebrew:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

follow [their documentation](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash-completion):

> Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile:

```bash
[[ -r "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

restart your terminal or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 6):

For macOS Monterey, the following works:

Edit the `.zprofile` file in your home directory. This can be done with a text editor. Path: `~/.zprofile`

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:make:*' tag-order 'targets'
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

After that, everything works correctly, tips work when you press TAB.

This method does not display anything extra when entering the terminal, unlike the methods indicated above.